# Getting correct paragraph to show when certain div is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three child divs that have their own id. Under the parent div of those three child divs are three classes each having paragraphs in them that talk about information of each of those child divs.

When I click on one of the child id divs, I want the correct class with the paragraph info for the div that was clicked to display under it. Here is what I have so far:

Here is a jsfiddle I have started: http://jsfiddle.net/kfe126w1/

Here is the code if you dont want to go see the js fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="main"</div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="info">
    <h1>Title of left id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of left id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the left id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the left id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info">
    <h1>Title of middle id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of middle id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the middle id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the middle id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info">
    <h1>Title of right id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of right id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the right id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the right id div</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    width:100%;
}

#left{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    /* An image sprite will go here and also a hover id #left:hover below  */
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#middle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    /* An image sprite will go here and also a hover id #middle:hover below  */
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#right{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    /* An image sprite will go here and also a hover id #right:hover below  */
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
}

#clear{
    clear:both;
}

.info{
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').hide();
});
```

Would be grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to each info div, according to id:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="info left">
    <h1>Title of left id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of left id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the left id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the left id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info middle">
    <h1>Title of middle id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of middle id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the middle id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the middle id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info right">
    <h1>Title of right id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of right id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the right id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the right id div</p>
</div>
```

Add a function handling the hover:

```
$('.main div').hover(function(){
    $('.info').hide(); //Hide them all
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the clicked div id
    $('.' + id ).show(); //Show the div you want according to id
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I caught the mistake after I commented. I keep trying to complicate things. This was way more simple than I was trying to make it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the corresponding info div. So in the info section representing the left's content, add a "left" class...and so on. Also add a 'section' class (for example) to each div that that is responsible for toggling the info's content. Then in the JavaScript, you're basically going to setup a click handler for this .section class and toggle based on the classes you setup. It's much easier to see this through code, so here you are!

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="section" id="left"></div>
    <div class="section" id="middle"></div>
    <div class="section" id="right"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="info left"></div>
<div class="info middle"></div>
<div class="info right"></div>
```

In the JavaScript, do this:

```
$('.section').on("click", function() {
    var info_class = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.' + info_class).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kfe126w1/1/) what are you looking for?

Markup:

```
<div class="main"</div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="info left">
    <h1>Title of left id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of left id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the left id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the left id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info middle">
    <h1>Title of middle id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of middle id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the middle id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the middle id div</p>
</div>

<div class="info right">
    <h1>Title of right id div</h1>
    <h2>Sub title of right id div</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph about the right id div</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph about the right id div</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').hide();
});

$('.main').on('click', function(e){
    $('.info').hide();
    $('.'+e.target.id).show();
});
```